# Java formatter is not working properly

Tags: java, file, format, formatter

I have some questions about 'format' of formatter in Java.

First, I build my own code like below.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import static java.lang.Math.abs;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class MyServerAndroid extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;

private static ServerSocket ss;
private static Socket s;
private static BufferedReader br;
private static InputStreamReader isr;
private static String sensordata = "";
private static int portnum= 5556;
private static Formatter records;

//for CSV file's name
private static Date date = new Date();
private static SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd_HHmmss");
static String filename = dateformat.format(date);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MyServerAndroid frame = new MyServerAndroid();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    try {
        records = new Formatter("C:\\Users\\Choi\\Desktop\\research\\sensor_data_storage\\"+filename+".csv");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        int i = 0;
        while(true) {
            ss = new ServerSocket (portnum);
            s = ss.accept();
            isr = new InputStreamReader (s.getInputStream());
            br = new BufferedReader (isr);
            sensordata = br.readLine();

            Date date = new Date();
            Long current_time = date.getTime();

            System.out.println(current_time + " : " + sensordata);
            records.format(current_time + "," + sensordata + "\n");

            isr.close();
            br.close();
            ss.close();
            s.close();
            } 

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    records.flush();
    records.close();
}


/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public MyServerAndroid() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300); 
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    lblNewLabel.setBounds(27, 41, 350, 46); //x, y, width, height
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

    lblNewLabel2.setBounds(27, 80, 350, 46);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel2);
}
```

}

I think above there is no grammatical or syntactic error in above code.
But the problems and questions are

1. When I run my code, it always create files with proper file name. 
    Sometimes the file has appropriate data, but sometimes it has no record even when the data is well transferred from another devices(like smartphone) and showed in the console window because of the below line.

   ```
   System.out.println("current_time + " : " + sensordata);
   ```

   I couldn't find any particular reason for two different results. Does anyone know the reason?
2. I don't know if formatter and format is the best way to store input record on my PC. Is there a better or more robust way for this kind of work? It yes, please recommend me the way.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't use `Formatter` for this, but a `BufferedWriter` wrapping a `FileWriter`. You should also look into using try-with-resources to close your streams.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any reason for that? Or Could you explain me the differences between Formatter and BufferedWriter?